# Searching and replacing n element on list - scheme

Tags: scheme

have got a problem with do this kind of code , can't figure how to search for a element (a) and replace i by ( b) , how to do it?  Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
(define subst
  (lambda (new old l)
    (cond
     ((null? l) (quote ()))
     ((atom? (car l))
      (cond
       ((eq? (car l) old) (cons new
                                (subst new old (cdr l))))
       (else (cons (car l)
                   (subst new old (cdr l))))))
     (else (cons (subst new old (car l))
                 (subst new old (cdr l)))))))
```

This will search through a list of S expressions and substitute every occurrence of `old` with an occurrence of `new`.

Answer (score 4):

Start with a list. If it's empty, leave it. If the first element is a list, then you want to call your function recursively. If the first element is equal to what your searching for, cons the replacement onto a recursive call of your function on the rest of the list- you need to keep searching. If none of the earlier conditions are true, cons the first element on to  a recursive call of your function for the rest of the list.

```
(define (find-replace a b list)
 (cond
  ((null? list) '())
  ((list? (car list)) (cons (find-replace a b (car list)) (find-replace a b (cdr list))))
  ((eq? (car list) a) (cons b (find-replace a b (cdr list))))
  (else
   (cons (car list) (find-replace a b (cdr list))))))
```

Comment: Damn thanks for fast reply but dunno how to implenet it in my example, I mean that I want to run function send list and change a for b like:  (function '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 4 8))                                                   and the output should be                                                 (1 2 3 8 5 6) ... Please help :)

Comment: Do you have any experience with Scheme at all? The functions Sam and I gave you both do what you want, the only difference is the order that you call it. So for my example (find-replace 4 8 '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) yields (1 2 3 8 5 6). If you want to change it to be like how you want, then change the first line to (define (find-replace list a b) (or you can replace find-replace with whatever name you want).

Comment: HI @Greg How about this output:
(find-replace '(4 5) '(8 10) '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6)) yields (1 2 3 (8 10) 6)

How can we do this?